# how to convert expandable listview to listview with recycler list view as child?

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview

how to convert expandable list view to  list view with recycle list view as child in android

and display like google play store..

how to convert expandable list view to list view.....
i need your help to reovle my problem..advance thanks
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGJ4b.png)

here is json:

```
{
  "category": [
    {
      "id": "23",
      "category_name": "Sports",
      "category_image": "avenger,jpg",
      "sub_category": [
        {
          "id": "6",
          "name": "Cricket"
        },
        {
          "id": "9",
          "name": "footbal"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "24",
      "category_name": "General Knowledge",
      "category_image": "|avengers.jpg",
      "sub_category": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "name": "Science"
        }
      ]
    },


  ]
}
```

here is ExpandableListAdapter:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

here Is JsonParser:

```
public class JSONParser {

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String serviceUrl) {
        Boolean registered = false;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        URL url = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {

            url = new URL(serviceUrl);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setDoOutput(false);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (status != 200) {
                throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
            }
            registered = true;

            // Get Response
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);

            }
            rd.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      /* ErrorLogger.writeLog(claimNo, "Error Msg : "+e.getMessage()+"..."+ErrorLogger.StackTraceToString(e), "sendSyncService Failed");
         response.append("Error");*/
        }
        Log.v("Response:", response.toString());
        return response.toString();

    }

}
```

Here Is Main Actrivity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    private ProgressDialog mprocessingdialog;
    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/quiz/13.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        mprocessingdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        new DownloadJason().execute();

    }

    private class DownloadJason extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

//            Showing Progress dialog

            mprocessingdialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
            mprocessingdialog.setMessage("Loading");
            mprocessingdialog.setCancelable(false);
            mprocessingdialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mprocessingdialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONParser jp = new JSONParser();
            String jsonstr = jp.makeServiceCall(url);
            Log.d("Response = ", jsonstr);

            if (jsonstr != null) {
//            For Header title Arraylist
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
//                Hashmap for child data key = header title and value = Arraylist (child data)
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

                try {



                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                    JSONArray dataArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("category");
                    for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject internalObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        listDataHeader.add(internalObject.getString("category_name"));

                        JSONArray jsonArray = internalObject.getJSONArray("sub_category");

                        ArrayList<String> subCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(int j=0;j<jsonArray.length();j++)
                        {
                            subCategoryList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));

                        }

                        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i),subCategoryList);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Check internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            mprocessingdialog.dismiss();
//call constructor
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

            // setting list adapter
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Convert expandlelistview to simple list view and child items display horizenly...@HB

Comment: Convert? You don't convert it, you implement it. Your question is unclear and broad. So you are basically asking how to implement a horizontal scrollview?

Comment: yes ...ciled items display horizenaly